# Create Event register duplicated events

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use Microsoft Graph API to read/create events in Outlook agenda. The issue is when I try to create an event following the documentation ( https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0 ) the event is created twice in my Calendar 
[Event "Meeting time" appearing twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPIqh.jpg)

Here is my PHP code :

```
$json = '{
            "subject": "Meeting time",
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2018-11-30T09:00:00",
                "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2018-11-30T10:30:00",
                "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
            }
        }';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);  //Post Fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json),
    'Prefer: outlook.timezone="Pacific Standard Time"',
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXX...XXXXXXX"
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

I tried to use the PHP Microsoft Graph library and the result is the same. But when I use the Graph Explorer the created event is not duplicated. I think I missed something.

Comment: are you certain, it is not about executing the code twice?

Comment: Yes I'm. I've a `die` just after `curl_close`

Comment: I don't know what happened but I re-execute my code without changes and it work without doubling my events...

Comment: Same here, was not able to reproduce the duplication, same goes to utilizing Microsoft Graph SDK for PHP, everything seems works as expected